# For loop to print indices of enum, but not values

Tags: java, enums

```
public enum Months{
JANUARY("first"), FEBRUARY("second"), MARCH("third"), APRIL("fourth"), MAY("fifth"), JUNE("sixth"), JULY("seventh"), 
AUGUST("eigth"), SEPTEMBER("ninth"), OCTOBER("tenth"), NOVEMBER("eleventh"), DECEMBER("twelfth");

private String name;
// value in parentheses after elements
Months(String name){
    this.name = name;
}
public String getName(){
    return name;
}
public String toString(){
    return name;
}
```

this is my enum

```
public class Test {
   public static void main(String [] args){
   for(Months m : Months.values()){
      System.out.println(m);
   }
```

This is my main method. But this for loop accesses the toString method and prints the values of the indices, i.e. first, second, etc. 
Is there some way I can loop through and print the indices, i.e. JANUARY, FEBRUARY, etc.?

Comment: You can get `m.name()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need to do is `change System.out.println(m);` to `System.out.println(m.name())` :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    for (Months m : Months.values()) {
        System.out.println(m.name()); // Change is in this line.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

All `enum` elements provide a `name()` method, which will give you the identifier used to define the element, e.g. `Month.JANUARY.name()` will be `"JANUARY"`.